# How to pass "nil" constant to the untyped parameter?

Tags: delphi, untyped-variables

is it possible to pass nil as an undeclared constant to the untyped parameter of some function?
I have functions like these and I would like to pass some constant to the `Data` parameter to satisfy the compiler. Internally I'm deciding by the Size parameter. I know I can use Pointer instead of untyped parameter but it's much more comfortable for my case.

Now I'm getting `E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'RS232_SendCommand' that can be called with these arguments`

```
function RS232_SendCommand(const Command: Integer): Boolean; overload;
begin
  // is it possible to pass here an undeclared constant like nil in this example?
  Result := RS232_SendCommand(Command, nil, 0);
end;

function RS232_SendCommand(const Command: Integer; const Data; const Size: Integer): Boolean; overload;
begin
  ...
end;
```

This works, but I would be glad if I could leave the variable declaration.

```
function RS232_SendCommand(const Command: Integer): Boolean; overload;
var
  Nothing: Pointer;
begin
  Result := RS232_SendCommand(Command, Nothing, 0);
end;
```

---

Solution is to use somthing like this.

```
function RS232_SendCommand(const Command: Integer): Boolean; overload;
begin
  // as the best way looks for me from the accepted answer to use this
  Result := RS232_SendCommand(Command, nil^, 0);

  // or it also possible to pass an empty string constant to the untyped parameter
  // without declaring any variable
  Result := RS232_SendCommand(Command, '', 0);
end;
```

I'm doing this because some of my commands have a data sent after command transmission.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easy:

```
RS232_SendCommand(Command, nil^, 0);
```

You just need to make sure that you don't access the Data parameter from inside `RS232_SendCommand`, but presumably that's what the 0 size parameter is for.

To my mind this is the best solution because it very explicitly states that you are passing something that cannot be accessed.

Comment: Wow, that's even smarter. I'll accept this as the answer at least because there was mentioned it's impossible. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure `nil^` could be classed as elegant! ;-) You just have to remember that this does not dereference the nil pointer.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>No, you can not.</strike> *not that I knew of*

> **Untyped Parameters**
>
> You can omit type specifications when declaring
>   **var**, **const**, and **out** parameters. (Value parameters must be typed.) For
>   example:
>
> > *procedure TakeAnything(const C);*
>
> declares a procedure called
>   TakeAnything that accepts a parameter of any type. When you call such
>   a routine, you cannot pass it a numeral or untyped numeric constant.
>
> > From: [Parameters (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29)

So, perhaps add another overloaded version without the const arg that you can call when Size = 0.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me a lot. From the sentence `you cannot pass it a numeral or untyped numeric constant` I found a way, an empty string constant: `Result := RS232_SendCommand(Command, '', 0);`